# Django For loop not outputting anything

Tags: python, html, django

Just getting into Django and im confused why this for loop isnt printing anything. Im not getting any errors, heres my code;

My Views Page;

```
GivenMovies = [
    {
        'Name': 'Thor',
        'Genre': 'Action',
        'Rating': '7.0',
        'Content': 'Mad Movie',
        'Date_Posted': 'January 18, 2017'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'Constantine',
        'Genre': 'Action, Sci-Fi',
        'Rating': '7.2',
        'Content': 'Another madness of a movie',
        'Date_Posted': 'January 18, 2015'
    }
]

def MainPage(request):
    AllMovies = {'Movies': GivenMovies}
    return render(request, 'Movies/HomePage.html', AllMovies)
```

my forloop;

```
{% extends "Movies/Parent.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1> is showing</h1>
  {% for Movies,Value in AllMovies.items %}
      <h1> {{ Movies.Name }} </h1>
      <p> Genre: {{ Values.Genre }} </p>
      <p> Rating: {{ Values.Rating }}</p>
      <p> Content: {{ Values.Content }} </p>
      <p> Posted on: {{ Values.Date_Posted }} </p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Could someone please point out where i am going wrong, thank you.

Comment: @AliAsgari I was following a tutorial online, i will use what you have said now though as its easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you load the context with the key `Movies` through this line:

```
AllMovies = {'Movies': GivenMovies}
```

So in your template you should access the variable with that name; change the line:

```
{% for Movies,Value in AllMovies.items %}
```

**BUT**: the content of `GivenMovies` is a `list` not a `dict`, so calling `.items` won't work either. Just iterate over the list, maybe using this:

```
{% for item in Movies %}
  <h1> {{ item.Name }} </h1>
  <p> Genre: {{ item.Genre }} </p>
  <p> Rating: {{ item.Rating }}</p>
  <p> Content: {{ item.Content }} </p>
  <p> Posted on: {{ item.Date_Posted }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```